# 7 Divs with background and Image each

Tags: css

I am trying to make this design[image]

and I already have except for the IMAGE on each div.

How can I position the images on that position?

I am using this code

```
.image {
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  top:33%
}
```

but my problem is on responsive, it does not stay on that position. This is my code that I have.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: darkgray
}

#main {
  background: black url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x400") no-repeat center center /cover; 
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

#main > * {
  width: calc((100% / 4) - 1px);
  height: calc((100vw / 4) - 1px);
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: -1px -1px 0 0;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  transition: background-color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
#main > *:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.35);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#main > *:first-child {
  height: calc((100vw / 2) - 1px);
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 539px) {
  #main>* {
    width: calc((100% / 2) - 1px);
    height: calc((100vw / 2) - 1px);
  }
  #main>*:first-child {
    height: calc(100vw - 1px);
  }
}


.icon {
       position:absolute;
      width:100px;
      top:33%
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div> 
   <img class="icon" src ="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    Excellence 
  </div>
  <div> <img class="icon" src ="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    Quality </div>
  <div> <img class="icon" src ="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">Efficiency </div>
  <div> <img class="icon" src ="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">Creativity </div>
  <div> <img class="icon" src ="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">Faith </div>
  <div> <img class="icon" src ="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">Effectiveness </div>
  <div> <img class="icon" src ="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">Teamwork </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be a lot easier to have 7 elements with a white border on top of an element with the entire background.

Comment: This will be a pain in the ass and probably not responsive. I'd do as James recommended.

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you please explain more. Thanks

Comment: @JamesDonnelly i was adding other duplicates ... his issue is keeping the image inside their div which is equivalent to keep them centered and then he can play with margin if he don't want a perfect centering. And there is a lot of Dup for that

Comment: @JamesDonnelly and check his codepen he's already having 7 element above one background ... and his issue is with the image inside each element

Comment: @TemaniAfif CodePen is blocked at my office. The content of the question doesn't make this appear to be a duplicate.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly is a perfect duplicate because i checked the pen ... and the issue is with the image positionned absolute inside each div .. i don't close question without reading carefully

Comment: @JamesDonnelly i created a snippet with his code, so you can check it now and see his real issue

Comment: By the way guys, my code snippet is responsive, even on mobile, my only problem is the IMAGE on each DIV when I resize the browser. it should on that position even resized.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly yes you have issue with the image which was the puporse of the duplicate, but now check my answer below and you will get it fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the code like this.

You need to make the parent div `position:relative` and center the image using `margin:auto`. Then you can add some translation to adjust the position.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: darkgray
}

#main {
  background: black url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x400") no-repeat center center /cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

#main>* {
  width: calc((100% / 4) - 1px);
  height: calc((100vw / 4) - 1px);
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: -1px -1px 0 0;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  transition: background-color .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  position: relative;
}

#main>*:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .35);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#main>*:first-child {
  height: calc((100vw / 2) - 1px);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 539px) {
  #main>* {
    width: calc((100% / 2) - 1px);
    height: calc((100vw / 2) - 1px);
  }
  #main>*:first-child {
    height: calc(100vw - 1px);
  }
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  margin:  auto;
  transform:translate(0,-30px);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div>
    <img class="icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"> Excellence
  </div>
  <div> <img class="icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"> Quality </div>
  <div> <img class="icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">Efficiency </div>
  <div> <img class="icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">Creativity </div>
  <div> <img class="icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">Faith </div>
  <div> <img class="icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">Effectiveness </div>
  <div> <img class="icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">Teamwork </div>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW! that's awesome! What this code mean

transform:translate(0,-30px); ?

Comment: @JohnDaveManuel the image is centred so by adding a translate i push it back to top by 30px so -30px from the center ... you can adjust as you want this value ;)

Comment: I see. Thank you guys! I have been stuck in here for couple of hours

Comment: Hello! I like to ask what I need to change in CSS if I want to put "EXCELLENCE" part on the right instead in left